# Magento Admin :: Remove Menu item for specific Roles/Users

Tags: php, magento

I want to remove a menu item from the adminmenu for a specific user role. I've seen others do it by creating a dummy override but these are not based on roles. I want to do this without using one of the .xml files. 
Is there a way to do this in, for example; the __construct() or prepareLayout?

EDIT: 
I must add to this that the part I want to disable is the Manage Hierarchy item in CMS.
I know I can just disable the Hierarchy for the userrole but I need it to save CMS pages.

Comment: OK, so I managed to fix this myself.
I extended Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Page_Menu within my local Xxxxx_Xxxx_Block_Adminhtml_Page_Menu

Comment: +1 for sharing the solution :)

Comment: Please submit your solution as an answer as soon as possible.

Comment: I was only able to do that after 8 hours of submitting.
So I did it just now.
Tomorrow I can mark it as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I extendend the Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Page_Menu with my own block.
I copied the function "_buildMenuArray()"
And just before I return the menu array I check if the current loggen in user is not the admin. If so; I remove the Hierarchy item from the menu and set the Page item with value last so the drop-shadow is displayed properly.

```
class Xxxxx_Xxxx_Block_Adminhtml_Page_Menu extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Page_Menu
{
    protected function _buildMenuArray(Varien_Simplexml_Element $parent=null, $path='', $level=0)
    {
        if (is_null($parent)) {
            $parent = Mage::getSingleton('admin/config')->getAdminhtmlConfig()->getNode('menu');
        }

        $parentArr = array();
        $sortOrder = 0;
        foreach ($parent->children() as $childName => $child) {
            if (1 == $child->disabled) {
                continue;
            }

            $aclResource = 'admin/' . ($child->resource ? (string)$child->resource : $path . $childName);
            if (!$this->_checkAcl($aclResource)) {
                continue;
            }

            if ($child->depends && !$this->_checkDepends($child->depends)) {
                continue;
            }

            $menuArr = array();

            $menuArr['label'] = $this->_getHelperValue($child);

            $menuArr['sort_order'] = $child->sort_order ? (int)$child->sort_order : $sortOrder;

            if ($child->action) {
                $menuArr['url'] = $this->_url->getUrl((string)$child->action, array('_cache_secret_key' => true));
            } else {
                $menuArr['url'] = '#';
                $menuArr['click'] = 'return false';
            }

            $menuArr['active'] = ($this->getActive()==$path.$childName)
                || (strpos($this->getActive(), $path.$childName.'/')===0);

            $menuArr['level'] = $level;

            if ($child->children) {
                $menuArr['children'] = $this->_buildMenuArray($child->children, $path.$childName.'/', $level+1);
            }
            $parentArr[$childName] = $menuArr;

            $sortOrder++;
        }

        uasort($parentArr, array($this, '_sortMenu'));

        while (list($key, $value) = each($parentArr)) {
            $last = $key;
        }
        if (isset($last)) {
            $parentArr[$last]['last'] = true;
        }

        $data = $this->_isAdmin($parentArr);

        return $data;
    }

    protected function _isAdmin($data){
        $userRole = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->getUser()->getRole();
        $roleName = $userRole->getRoleName();
        $roleId = $userRole->getRoleId();
        if ($roleName == 'Administrators' || $roleId == 1) {
            return $data;
        } else {
            if (isset($data['hierarchy'])){
                unset($data['hierarchy']);
                $data['page']['last'] = 1;  
            }
            if (isset($data['enterprise_page']['children']['hierarchy'])){
                unset($data['enterprise_page']['children']['hierarchy']);
                $data['enterprise_page']['children']['last'] = 1;
            }
            return $data;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this is to edit ACL permissions for the role. This is a feature in the Magento admin and there's no need for a custom module.

You go to the System:Permissions:Roles. Then you select the role that you want to remove the menu item from. In the Role Resources tabs, you select the menu items you want to show in that role's admin. Click save and clear your cache and you should be good.

Comment: As I said in the description. The role 'hierarchy' must be activated in order to save CMS pages. If I shut it off, the CMS pages get saved without the hierarchy information. And when you activate a role (hierarchty) in the Roles menu. The menu item for that role (hierarchy) is automaticlly added to the menu bar.